# Synthesizing hazard ratios that are based on different comparisons (meta-analysis)

Tags: meta-analysis, hazard, proportional-hazards

I intend to evaluate the effect of an exposure (E), continuous, on my outcome (O), binary. The available cohort studies are based on time-to-event analysis and report hazard ratios (HR). However, there is no clear cut-off for the E in the literature so the available studies use a multitiude of arbitrary cut-offs for defining those that have the E vs those that don't (some examples are as follows):

1- Comparing 4th quartile of the E to the 1st quartile

2- Comparing 3rd tertile to the middle tertile or the first of E

3- Comparing E above the median (Q3+Q4) to the E below median (Q1+Q2)

4- Comparing the E in the 5th quintile to the first quintile

My main question is: **Is there a standard way for calculating a unified HR?**

What I have seen in the literature so far there are 2 main approaches:

1. Ignoring the difference in basis of comparisons and synthesize the given HRs as they are.
2. Calculating a "per standard deviation(SD) HR", by converting the mean difference between strata to the SD of E in that study.
   (e.g., (mean of E in the 5th quintile - mean of E in the first quintile)/[SD of E]) for example 4) (However, many studies don't provide the value for their cut-offs and we have to rely on the conversion between SD and IQR to estimate them: SD*1.35 = IQR)

Considering the lack of some part of data in each study for approach #2, we have to estimate a lot of factors (such as the value of quantiles, SD and mean for the E) which will quickly add up.
So overall, should I go with approach number 1? is there a better way for estimating approach number 2? Is there any better approach?

p.s. The distribution of E is usually significantly skewed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.